# How to use variables as input for xmlstarlet val?

Tags: shell, xmlstarlet

How can I use variables as input for xmlstarlet validate command? 
Here is the complete example:

```
read -r -d '' XML <<"EOF"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
EOF

# emits a usage message, exits with status 2
xmlstarlet val -v . <<< "$XML"

# also emits a usage message and exits with status 2
xmlstarlet val -v - <<< "$XML"
```

Comment: BTW, note that generally, we ask that your questions contain a **specific error message** (or, otherwise, description of actual behavior), avoiding the phrase "does not work". (If it worked, you wouldn't be here; what does it do instead? Exit with an error? Which error? Return immediately to the prompt with no output? If so, with what exit status? Etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the invalid `-v` argument, and your command parses correctly:

```
$ xmlstarlet val - <<<"$XML"
- - valid
```